# java rest client gets Remotely closed error on connection to kubernetes minikube service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, kubernetes, minikube

I'm developing a service that will run in Kubernetes. For functional testing of this service our tests will deploy the service to minikube running on a laptop.

In the most basic test the java client just pings a health check endpoint of the service. The java client uses Jersey and creates the client simply like:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
..
 private static final Client CLIENT = ClientBuilder.newClient();

The request fails with;
2017-08-04 13:57:55.202 WARNING [PingTest] Remotely closed
2017-08-04 13:57:55.206 INFO [system.err] javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Remotely closed
2017-08-04 13:57:55.207 INFO [system.err]     at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly.connector.GrizzlyConnector.apply(GrizzlyConnector.java:260)
2017-08-04 13:57:55.207 INFO [system.err]     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
2017-08-04 13:57:55.208 INFO [system.err]     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
..
```

But I can invoke the same endpoint running in minikube directly in curl or from Postman.

The requests sent from the 3 different clients are essentially the same (except for the user-agent):

```
--POSTNAME--
GET /20170101/health HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f899c540-e93a-479b-9e8b-c58e356140d7
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/6.2.5
Accept: /
Host: localhost:31081
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

--CURL--
GET /20170101/health HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:31081
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: /

--JAVA TEST--
GET /20170101/health HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Jersey/2.24.1 (Async HTTP Grizzly Connector 2.24.1)
Host: localhost:31081
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: /
```

Any ideas of why I can access the endpoint from curl or Postman but not from a java client?

Comment: please post a full stack trace with a readable code

Comment: Here's the stack trace;

Comment: 2017-08-04 16:56:17.592 INFO [system.err] javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Remotely closed
2017-08-04 16:56:17.594 INFO [system.err]  at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly.connector.GrizzlyConnector.apply(GrizzlyConnector.java:260)
2017-08-04 16:56:17.594 INFO [system.err]  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
2017-08-04 16:56:17.595 INFO [system.err]  at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
...

Comment: The code is just;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

   private static final Client CLIENT = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 
    Response r = null;
        try {
            r = CLIENT.target(instance.url().path(TestConstants.HEALTH_API)
                                   .request()
                                   .get();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a timing issue, there is a call back method meant to wait until the containers get to ready status before invoking the service endpoints but found a code path that bypassed the callback.